# Replace Font Awesome Icon with Desired Image

Tags: javascript, php, icons

> I want to replace font-awesome icons with my desired images

I have tried few codes like `:before {content: url("https://hhbchat.com/chatroom/img/crown.jpg") !important;}`but it is not helping.

I want to replace the icons with pictures that i want and current code is `.fa-headphones:before{content:"\f025"}` i want to replace headphones with Crown image which is available on my website directory. The Crown image should be seen inside the chatroom in user list which is available at https://hhbchat.com/chatroom

Please help or guide me to make the changes.

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.fa-headphones:before{content:""}
.fa-headphones{background-image: url("https://hhbchat.com/chatroom/img/crown.jpg")  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for your time and kind reply. i have tried the code and it is still not working :(